# Ninject: Resolve list of all registered types with constructor parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I am able to get a list of all the registered types by doing

```
var myTypes = kernel.Get<List<IMyInterface>>();
```

The MyType implementations need to take in a constructor argument though. I thought I could accomplish this by doing

```
kernel.Get<List<IMyInterface>>(
    new ConstructorArgument("argName", argValue ) );
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I get an exception saying it's trying to resolve the parameter "argName" and can't. I'm guessing it's trying to use that arg for the List, and not each type in the list.

Is there a way to do this?

**Update:**

I'm able to do this in a round about way by doing

```
var types = 
    from t in typeof(IMyInterface).Assembly.DefinedTypes
    where typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(t)
    where t.IsClass
    select (IMyInterface)kernel.Get(t,
        new ConstructorArgument("argName", argValue));
```

This is not ideal.

**Update:**

I ended up changing my class constructor to not take in the parameter. I think it was not a good DI practice the way I had it working.

Comment: In general, if you need to inject some configuration value into multiple implementations, you are missing an abstraction. What exactly is this `argValue` that you want to inject? Is this a configuration string perhaps?

Comment: It's a value that I get from a service call. I have a bunch of implementations of an interface and I'm looping them and calling a method `Execute` on them. I figured that this value should be a constructor arg, and not a param of the execute method.

Comment: I have a feeling that my argument should probably be part of a method on IMyInterface, instead of a constructor arg. Please feel free to comment on this.

Comment: In general, compile-time, design-time, and configuration-time values should be passes through constructors (or properties) while runtime values should be passed through methods. If I understand correctly, what you're having seems like a runtime value. But unfortunately, without a concrete example, my feedback can't be more concrete.

Comment: @Steven This case definitely is a runtime value and your statement makes sense. I changed my class to not take that value in the constructor and am using it as a argument to a method call instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify constructor arguments in the type Bindings

```
kernel.Bind<IMyInterface>().To<MyType>().WithConstructorArgument("argName",argValue);
```

With that binding in place, argValue will be injected into MyType constructor.

UPDATE:

If the argument is known only in runtime, you could do it like this:

In the binding get the value for construtor from request parameters:

```
 kernel.Bind<IMyInterface>().To<MyType>().WithConstructorArgument("argName",
            r => r.Parameters.First().GetValue(r.Request.ParentContext, r.Request.Target));
```

When creating instance, pass the parameter into request:

```
kernel.Get<List<IMyInterface>>( new Ninject.Parameters.Parameter("argName",argValue) );
```

Comment: I don't have the value until runtime.

Comment: @JoshClose updated the answer, but passing constructor arguments like that is kind of against DI principles. But it should work.

Comment: Interesting. I will give that a try. I'm not sure of another way to set this up. I have on parameter that is Ninject managed, and one that is dynamic and got just before I need to resolve. I'm sure there's a better way than what I'm doing, I'm just not sure what it is.

Comment: It's important to stress what @jure just said: you should not use constructor arguments for runtime values.

Answer (score 2):

If you want all registered types you should use `GetAll<T>` instead of `Get<List<T>>`:

```
kernel.GetAll<IMyInterface>(new ConstructorArgument("argName",argValue));
```

you can materialize that as a list if you really need to using LINQ's `ToList`.

Comment: I have a similar requirement but i didn't get it working "var myList = kernel.GetAll<IMyInterface>().ToList(); Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>().WithConstructorArgument("myList", myList);" . myList is empty. What am I missing